# Google App Engine Launcher Windows - Extra Command Line Flags

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-launch

I'm using Google App Engine Launcher with SDK release 1.9.40 for Windows.

It seems that I am unable to save extra command line flags for my application in my application settings. Any flags I write in "Launch Settings" don't save after updating.

I've used the SDK on a Mac as well and the Mac version of the Launcher does save my flags.

I would prefer to use GAE Launcher on Windows than run the dev server through the command line and was wondering if I was missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open issue about this problem: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13070

As a workaround while this is not solved you can modify manually the google_appengine_projects.ini which is located in *C:\Users\USERNAME\Google*. You have to add a line for each additional parameter, e.g.:

```
path = [PROJECT_PATH]
admin_port = 8006
name = [PROJECT_NAME]
port = 9080
flag0 = [FIRST_FLAG]
flag1 = [SECOND_FLAG]
```

Comment: I added the flag storage_path = my_path but it did not recognize it. Is there any other way to fix this?